# C# Console Application still in memory after exit - Asynchronous Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asynchronous

I'm really new to C# and .Net. My boss asked me to create a timer using asyncronous callback using web service. I actaully created it, and got it to work, but whenever I close the console app window the web service is still running. When I rerun the app, it starts the counter from 0, but jumps back and forth to the number from the previous run (which is still in memeory).

The mainMethod() increaments the number by 1 every 10 sec, and monitorMethod() reads that number, and returns a string.

How do I stop the web service, and reset the counter back to 0 everytime I close the console window?

I hope this makes sense! Thanks in advance!

Here is my code.

**Web Service:**

```
 public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
 {
    private int iTotal;
    private int iCurrent;

    [WebMethod]
    public void mainMethod()
    {
        iTotal = 42;
        iCurrent = 1;
        Application["iTotal"] = iTotal;
        Application["iCurrent"] = iCurrent;
        // sleep 10 seconds
        while (iCurrent <= iTotal)
        {
            Application["iCurrent"] = iCurrent;
            iCurrent++;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);                
        }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string monitorMethod()
    {
        iCurrent = int.Parse(Application["iCurrent"].ToString());
        iTotal = int.Parse(Application["iTotal"].ToString());
        if (iCurrent <= iTotal)
        {
            return iCurrent + " of " + iTotal;
        }
        else
            return "DONE";
    }
  }
}
```

**Client Side**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Service1 client = new Service1(); //web service proxy
        client.mainMethodCompleted += new mainMethodCompletedEventHandler(client_mainMethodCompleted);

        if (Session["value"] == null)
        {
            Session["value"] = true;
        }

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            client.BeginmainMethod(AsyncCallback, null);
            string scriptFunction = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">function reSubmit(){ document.getElementById(\"" + btnProcessNext.ClientID + "\").click(); }</script>";
            this.RegisterClientScriptBlock("s1", scriptFunction);
            string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">setTimeout(\"reSubmit()\", 500);</script>";
            this.RegisterStartupScript("submit", script);
        }
        else
        {
            if (StringParseByMe(lblStatus.Text))
            {
                string scriptFunction = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">function reSubmit(){ document.getElementById(\"" + btnProcessNext.ClientID + "\").click(); }</script>";
                this.RegisterClientScriptBlock("s1", scriptFunction);
                string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">setTimeout(\"reSubmit()\", 500);</script>";
                this.RegisterStartupScript("submit", script);
            }
            else
                return;
        }
    }

    protected void btnProcessNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Service1 client = new Service1();
        string label = client.monitorMethod();
        Session["value"] = StringParseByMe(label);
        lblStatus.Text = label;
    }

    private bool StringParseByMe(string sparse)
    {
        if (sparse == "DONE")
            return false;

        string[] sparseArray = sparse.Split(' ');
        if (int.Parse(sparseArray[0]) == int.Parse(sparseArray[2]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

    void client_mainMethodCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Service1 client = new Service1();
        client.EndmainMethod(ar);
    }

    public void AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

**Web Page**

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2>
    Counter</h2>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text="0 of -1" Font-Bold="True" 
    Font-Size="XX-Large" ForeColor="#CC0000"></asp:Label>
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnProcessNext" runat="server" Text="Refresh" 
    onclick="btnProcessNext_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: is closing the console window supposed to stop the service?

Comment: yes, its suppose to completely stop and reset.

Comment: Why are you using Application state?

Comment: The thread you launch never ends.  What else do you expect?  Your code  is doing exactly what it should.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a button on the page and write the logic of stopping the timer in the button's click event. After that, generate a script to close the window.

Answer (score 1):

Even though your client was terminated, the async call to mainMethod() is still underway.  The web service does not know the client is gone and continues to run.

By starting a second client, your code makes a second call to mainMethod() and now two instances are running.  Both are trying to update the Application's iTotal and iCurrent values.  This is why the numbers appear to bounce back and forth.

You need to tell one of the mainMethod() threads to stop updating the Application values and to terminate.

So,
there are a variety of ways of doing that, but a simple way might be something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public void mainMethod()
{
    iTotal = 42;
    iCurrent = 1;
    int iReference = (int)(Application["iReference"] ?? 0);
    ++iReference;
    Application["iReference"] = iReference;
    Application["iTotal"] = iTotal;
    while( (iCurrent <= iTotal) && ((int)(Application["iReference"]) == iReference) )
    {
        Application["iCurrent"] = iCurrent;
        ++iCurrent;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( 10000 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The IIS worker process is probably still running.  You'll need to kill the w3wp.exe that's running.

Comment: yes, but what can I put in my code that will make it stop whenever I close the console window.